# Can you do a Nextjs App Production Build on Dev Machine and Later move .Next folder to the Server?

Tags: express, next.js

I'm deploying my first my Nextjs App and after reading several articles I am still confused about certain things. My app requires server side rendering and I need to do a Next Build. My goal is to host my app on an AWS EC2 instance using Express

1. Can I run Next build on my dev machine and later move the .next
   folder to the Prod Server? All the articles that I read are asking
   to move the enitre dev folder( including raw JS files) to Prod Server
   first and do a build on Prod Server. Is that the only way to do it?
2. I was able to do a Next Build on my Dev machine and it produced a .Next folder. But the package.json file INSIDE the .Next Folder only has one line called {"type": "commonjs"} and nothing else. Do I need to modify this file further to run the app on the server?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to understand is that Nextjs uses a server under the hood, an actual server to serve the pages. Its not a Single Page Application library/framework in which one can build all of the frontend assets and then copy the build folder somewhere in the express or some sort of server.

Since Nextjs itself is a server behind, you can either choose that(default) or you can also choose a custom express server. Hence this server needs your dev files and not just the build folder.
If you want to use the custom server, read more on how to do it here https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server